# C# string.IndexOf method doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I am using C# to remove a special character from a string:

```
while (str.Contains("@"))
    str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("@"), 1);
```

but this produce an error:

> StartIndex can not be less than zero.

The `str` variable really contains `@` character but the result value of IndexOf() method is -1.

I guess that is because the string encoding is utf-8, but I don't know how to manipulate the string.

The value of `str` is `NfyCAlcvxu1Xqw@ًں‘„ًں`.

Comment: can u show a sample string give the error?

Comment: NfyCAlcvxu1Xqw@ًں‘„ًں

Comment: based on your example try: `str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("@ً"), 1);` instead as your string doesn't contain an actual `@` but a `@ً`

Comment: also don't use a `while()`, use `if()` instead, unless there are multiple `@` possible

Comment: Your code is correct. Which .net version are you using?

Comment: @ً is 2 characters that @ is one of them.

Comment: I am using VS 2015.

Comment: dotnet framework 4.5

Comment: Well, String.Contains() doesn't do what you hoped it does.  It is slightly evil, it tries to find the substring as fast as possible, using ordinal comparison.  Don't re-invent String.Replace() please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN of [`string.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison. The search begins at the first character position of this string and continues through the last character position.

So you have to use ordinal comparison also in the `IndexOf` :

```
while (str.Contains("@"))
    str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("@",StringComparison.Ordinal), 1);
```

Comment: @AmirZojaji You should ask the opposite: What causes the problem? The mixture of left-to-right and right-to-left chars

Answer (score 1):

That bit of code that you provided alone, seems to be fine.

However, I would suggest a different approach to the problem:

**C#**

```
str = str.Replace("@", "");
```

Comment: You provided the example string in a comment. This code is related to your question, not your comments.

Comment: @JanR If this is not real @ character, why contains method returns true?

Comment: @DesertFox I provided it in comment in answer of another comments. this is not important in my question.

Comment: of course it is. And if you cannot see that as important, this might say something about why you are asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I used it in the question.